# How to click on this element in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to click this element with Python Selenium. The element seems to be located within a table if that is relevant. I've also already tried waiting until the element is present as well, but no luck. Here is the code I've written so far:

```
chrome_browser.find_element_by_xpath(f"//a[contains(text(),'90099029279')]").click()
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="/lightning/r/a5f3o000001A2Z2AAK/view" data-id="a5f3o000001A2Z2AAK" tabindex="-1">3418-3420 19th Street, San Francisco, CA 94110- 90099029279</a>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: What error is returned?

Comment: any iframes involved, that xpath looks good.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use CSS selector to find this element. (I am using this way just to be sure i get correct selector)
   Open that page in browser, Ctrl + shift + C, then again  Ctrl + shift + C to select an element in the page to inspect it, right click at the code -> Copy -> Copy selector

```
btn = chrome_browser.find_element_by_css_selector('css selector')
btn.click()
```

2. Locate Hyperlink by Link Text

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('3418-3420 19th Street, San Francisco, CA 94110- 90099029279').click()
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('90099029279').click()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use pyautogui module, though you need to install it first:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 150) # Move the mouse to XY coordinates.
pyautogui.click()
```

It presses the mouse at whatever spot you want it to press (in your case, the button).
I hope this is helpful:)